# Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, timer, nullpointerexception

I have the code below,and it shows me an exception which is: Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. The erros is in line : jLabel1.setIcon(black); If I delete this line,then it works well. Any idea? Thank you !

```
Icon black=createImageIcon("black.PNG");

protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = Frame1.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

public Frame1(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RunMeTask(), 1000,1000);
    }


 public class RunMeTask extends TimerTask {
    public int k=0;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Run Me ~");
            jLabel1.setIcon(black);    //error
            k++;
            if (k==10) {
              timer.cancel();
            }
}
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Frame1(1);
    System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Frame1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where is `jLable1` initialized or declared?

Comment: You havent shown us the code where jLabel1 and black are decalred.

Comment: @tintinmj I use Netbeans,so I have declared on Design View.

Comment: @Deadron I edit my post and you can see where  I have declared black icon.

Comment: @user2933161 Here are two possibilities. **1.**  `jLabel1` is not initialized **2.** `createImageIcon` return `null` if `imgURL` is null. Make sure you have provided correct file path and file name.

Comment: @Smit createImageIcon has a println() and it is not show me that it can't find a file,so it is ok at this part. How can I initialize the jlabel ? I did what I do anytime I use a jlabel. :/

Comment: @user2933161 YOu have to initialized somewhere correct place in your code like `JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel()`. If you dont do `new XXX` then it will be `null` by default. For more details see [`--> Creating Objects <--`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Comment: Sorry to all,I found the error. I forget to use initComponents(); in public Frame1() . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Code either doesn't know what `jLabel1` is, or it doesn't know what `black` is. Make sure both are Objects within view of that run() method.

Comment: This isn't a compiler error. `NullPointerExceptions` show up when you run the program, indicating that everything compiled fine. The problem is that `jLabel1` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @musical_coder Can you help me? Where is the error exactly? I don't understand. Thank you !

Comment: Sorry, edited my wrong wordage. Here is what I would do to try and see what is happening: 1. set a println() in the createImageIcon method to make sure it is being called. (and that "Couldn't Find File" is not showing up) 2. set a debug marker on the line where the error is happening.

Comment: Also, make sure `Icon black=createImageIcon("black.PNG");` happens before `jLabel1.setIcon(black);`

Comment: @DoubleDouble createImageIcon has a println() and it is not show me that it can't find a file,so it is ok at this part..

Comment: Most likely jLabel1 is not initialized. If you are already calling `JLabel jLabel1` or something similar elsewhere, try doing `jLabel1 = new JLabel()` to see if the error is still thrown.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Sorry,I found the error. I forget to use initComponents(); in public Frame1() . Thank you !